# SEEK_FAILURE What to do if SetFilePointer fails if file is over 4.1 GB

Tags: windows, api, file, vb6, large-files

```
If SetFilePointer(hFile, 0&, ByVal 0&, FILE_END) _
    = INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER Then
```

This call raises the `HBF_SEEK_FAILURE` error (
45603) at some point of time.

The decoded API error message is:

> ```
> Seek Error 
> Error 87 
> Wrong parameter
> ```

I believe it fails when the file size is over 4.1 GB.

What could I do to work around this problem?

I have read [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070711-00/?p=26063) that this error is a valid response if a file is over 4 GB. So should I just ignore it?

According to a suggestion, I am now using the Ex version, but I get a Wrong DLL Calling Convention error:

```
Public Sub SeekEnd()
    RaiseErrorIfClosed
        
    If SetFilePointerEx(hFile, 0&, ByVal 0&, FILE_END) _
        = INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER Then
            RaiseError HBF_SEEK_FAILURE
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy solution; call `SetFilePointerEx` instead.

If you want to continue using `SetFilePointer` with large files then you should set the lpDistanceToMoveHigh parameter to a valid pointer (which may point to a value that is 0 in this specific case).

When lpDistanceToMoveHigh is set you can check the return value like this:

```
If SetFilePointer(...) = INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER _
AndAlso If Not Err.LastDLLError = 0
  ' Handle error
Else
  ' Success
End If
```

Here is a version that uses SetFilePointerEx

```
Private Declare Function SetFilePointerEx Lib "kernel32" ( _
        ByVal hFile As Long, _
        ByVal liDistanceToMove As Currency, _
        ByRef lpNewFilePointer As Currency, _
        ByVal dwMoveMethod As Long) As Boolean

Public Function SeekEOF() As Currency
'++++++ NEW
' Seek to a base 0 EOF and return the pointer position
' The returned value is the new ABSOLUTE pointer positon.
    Dim RetVal As Long
    Dim tmpPosition As Currency
    Dim returnedPosition As Currency
    RaiseErrorIfClosed
    tmpPosition = 0@
    RetVal = SetFilePointerEx(hFile, (tmpPosition), returnedPosition, FILE_END) ' seek relative to the END of the file. thius returns a pointer to the final byte ?
    If RetVal = 0 Then  ' failed
        RaiseError HBFH_SEEK_FAILURE
    End If
    fCurrentPointerPosition = (returnedPosition) * 10000@
    If fCurrentPointerPosition <> Me.fileSize() Then 'gosh, what could have happened ? BASE 0 compared to BASE 1 position should=file size (ie 1 past the last byte!)
        RaiseError HBFH_SEEK_FAILURE
    End If
    SeekEOF = fCurrentPointerPosition ' returns the BASE 0 absolute pointer positon which is 1 past the last byte
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please write out your code with the Ex version? I have tried it, and I got "Wrong DLL calling convention".

Comment: I don't have VB6 and I have not coded in VB in many years but I can tell you that the liDistanceToMove parameter is a 64-bit number. Perhaps `Declare Function SetFilePointerEx Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, ByVal liDistanceToMove As Currency, ByVal lpNewFilePointer_NULL As Long, ByVal dwMoveMethod As Long) As Long` but I'm not sure if Currency is the best substitute for INT64. See https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?531321-VB6-Huge-(-gt-2GB)-File-I-O-Class for how to deal with Currency (divide by 10000 or play games with custom types and `LSet` )

Comment: @tmighty Regarding your edit, are you sure "As Boolean" is 4 bytes? WinAPI BOOL is really a UINT32 (4 bytes, you might need "As Long").

Comment: @Anders - Correct. API functions that return BOOL should be declared as returning `Long` to VB6, because there's a mismatch between BOOL, which is a 32-bit value of 0 or 1, and `Boolean` which is a 16-bit value of 0 or -1. A conversion to `Boolean` can then be done with `CBool()` if needed.

Comment: `ByRef posHigh As Long` probably

Comment: All is good. The problem was something else.